# Android Studio rename package of a module which have a library module attached

Tags: android, android-studio

This is a follow up question to this question:
[Android Studio Rename Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package)

I got 2 app modules which uses another module as a library. One of the app modules had the same package name as the library and the other app module had another name. Now I want to change the module name which is the same one as the library to a have a different package name so I will have:

1) Package name for library - for example com.library.name

2) Package name for app1 - for example com.first.app

3) Package name for app2 - for example com.second.app

However, when I try to refactor, Android Studio wants to change the package name in the library as well, instead of changing it in the app alone.

How can I change the package name of a module without refactoring the package name of the library module as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create new package `com.first.app` in `app1` module
2. Drag and drop in
   Project navigator view (toggled by `Alt+7` or `Cmd+7` hotkey) the
   whole lot of classes and subpackages you wish to move to the new
   package
3. Repeat for rest of your modules respectively

---

Just to be clear. This is the Project navigator view:

[image]

Comment: I actually ended up just changing the name in the gradle file by refactoring which didn't cause troubles, and in the manifest I just renamed it and rebuilt everything which surprisingly worked well